# Content-Length gives size of entire file for first Partial Content response

Tags: http

I'm hosting a large (1.8GB) video file under Xampp.  I've created the following HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <video controls width="800" src="test01.mp4" />
    </body>
</html>
```

And (good news) the video is not downloaded all at once when the page loads - it is downloaded in pieces as needed to play the video.

However, I'm having trouble understanding the HTTP responses that are sent.  When I initially load the page, the first two HTTP requests regarding the video are:

```
GET http://localhost:90/movies/test01.mp4

Host: localhost:90
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0
Accept: video/webm,video/ogg,video/*;q=0.9,application/ogg;q=0.7,audio/*;q=0.6,*/*;q=0.5
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Referer: http://localhost:90/movies/
Range: bytes=0-
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Date: Mon, 09 Jul 2018 00:16:32 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.0g PHP/7.2.3
Last-Modified: Fri, 29 Jun 2018 09:00:33 GMT
ETag: "77ab7f58-56fc414a18560"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 2007727960
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
Content-Range: bytes 0-2007727959/2007727960
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: video/mp4
```

Second request headers:

```
Host: localhost:90
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0
Accept: video/webm,video/ogg,video/*;q=0.9,application/ogg;q=0.7,audio/*;q=0.6,*/*;q=0.5
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Referer: http://localhost:90/movies/
Range: bytes=1992327168-
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Second response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Date: Mon, 09 Jul 2018 00:16:35 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.0g PHP/7.2.3
Last-Modified: Fri, 29 Jun 2018 09:00:33 GMT
ETag: "77ab7f58-56fc414a18560"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 15400792
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
Content-Range: bytes 1992327168-2007727959/2007727960
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: video/mp4
```

The first response has `Content-Length: 2007727960` which is 1.8 GB.  However, the full video is not transferred - Firefox's network tab reports that the transferred data is only 54.75 MB.

The second request then asks for `Range: bytes=1992327168-` so somehow the browser could tell the response body length of the first response even with an incorrect `Content-Length` header.  Unlike the first response, the second response has `Content-Length` set correctly.

In the first request, why is `Content-Length` not set to the length of the response body [as it should be](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Length)?  How then does the client know how long the response body is?

Comment: Did you ever figure out the answer?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest explanation is that the Content-Length is indeed correct, but Firefox aborts the read operation after ~54MB.